# How do I find the base address of a Translation Table for initial lookup?

Tags: linux, arm64, page-tables, armv8

I'm working on code that is able to perform at Stage 1 Address Translation at EL2 in an AArch64-based system.

According to the documentation I need to store the base address of the first level of the translation table in TTBR0_EL2. However, there is no information on obtaining the base address of that translation table.

Is this something that I can look up in Linux? If so where would I find this information? I've tried looking in /dev/mem but everything is 0 there. I've also tried
`dmidecode --type memory` but that doesn't provide the information that I need.

Any help or resources that can help me would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in anticipation

Comment: The idea is that you build your own translation table and then that's the base address.